# including config.php not working

Tags: include, config, document-root

**After my doctype and html declaration, I have:**

```
<?php include ('/setup/config.php'); ?>
// leading slash to get to site root[?]

<?php $pageTitle = 'Home'; include ('header.php'); ?>

<body></body>
```

**And my config.php has:**

```
<?php 
define('ROOT',$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']); 
define('INCLUDES',ROOT.'/dir/dir/dir/'); 
?>
```

Content doesn't show up. What's wrong with my deal? - Tried without the leading slash, still doesn't work.

I figured my config file would have to be loaded first since it defines ROOT which all my other includes depend on...

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, leading slashes [/] don't work for getting to doc root in PHP as far as I can tell. So, I still had to use ../../../ etc. Then, the config.php file could be found. `:]`